# Get iterative output from for loop in C# windows forms constructor

Tags: c#, .net

my homework is to create a windows forms(.net framework) program in C# that outputs all numbers less than N except those that are divisible by 3 or 7 using constructors. Making this in console is easy. but in windows forms I don't know how to make the TextBox read all of the iterations in the constructor.

This is my code in the constructor:

```
class NumLess
{
    public string s;

    public NumLess (int N)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {

            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (i % 7 == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            s = i + ",";
        }

    }

}
```

And this is the code in the windows forms button:

```
        private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NumLess num = new NumLess(int.Parse(txtN.Text));
        txtResult.Text = "" + num.s;
    }
```

It only outputs the last iteration, I dont know what to do now.

Also, I've read something about this being easier with listbox and collections (not sure if I'm wording that the right way), but my teacher asked us to do it with Textbox and basic control structures, as you can see we are only starting to learn.

Thanks in advance

Comment: change `s = i + ",";` to `s = s + i + ",";` Keep in mind there are more efficient ways to do this. Look in to `StringBuilder`.

Comment: also you'd want to use `continue;` instead of `break;`, otherwise you'll only collect the numbers until one of them is divisible by 3 or 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the constructor:

```
    public NumLess (int N)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {

            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (i % 7 == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            s = i + ","; //will reset s every time
        }

    }
```

As you can see, the `operator=` overwrites what exists in `s`. There are many ways to fix this. For me to fix it, all I did was replace `=` with `+=` which will concatenate the current `s` with the new value. Replace:

```
s = i + ","; //will reset s every time
```

With:

```
s += i + ",";
```

You can also do these options:

```
s = string.Concat(s, string.Concat(i, ","));
```

```
s = s + i + ",";
```

Stringbuilders, as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0, are another option.

Also, as devcrp pointed out in the comments:

> also you'd want to use continue; instead of break;, otherwise you'll only collect the numbers until one of them is divisible by 3 or 7

Answer (score 0):

Try this version of NumLess class.

```
class NumLess
{
    public string s;

    public NumLess (int N)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {

            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (i % 7 == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            s = string.Concat(s, string.Concat(i, ","));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, totally forgot about continue.